# Read text file and move only those files to another folder

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ubuntu

I have a folder filled with 100 log files, some of them have data, some dont. I have a script that picks out the files with the data and have the names saved in a text file named "goodfiles.txt" I would like to know how i can read the files in the text file and move them to another folder. I have tried this: 
`cat /root/testing2/goodfiles.txt | xargs mv -f /root/testing2/moved/` 
but it gives me an error saying

mv: Target (log1508.log) must be a directory in order to move 
mv: directories or multiple files to it.

can someone please help me?

Comment: It looks like you're confusing the `-f` and `-t` options of GNU `mv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a slightly different, but conceptually simple approach (avoiding pipes):

```
for fileName in `cat goodfiles.txt`; do mv $fileName /root/testing2/moved/; done
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps to remember that you can change the part that  xargs replaces using the --replace option and specify the replacement string.  Otherwise it appends the line on the end.

I was able to do roughly the same with

```
cat filelist |xargs --replace='{}' mv {} ./targetdir/
```

For you
maybe try

```
cat /root/testing2/goodfiles.txt |xargs --replace '{}' /root/testing2/moved
```

Comment: I tried that but it gave me this error:
`xargs: illegal option -- -`

Comment: Can you put the specific command you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're confusing the `-f` option of GNU `mv` with the `-t` option, which is what you want here in order to move multiple sources to a single target with `xargs`

```
   mv [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

Note that plain `xargs` breaks input into whitespace delimited arguments, so your command would break if any of the filenames contains whitespace. Also it is a [UUOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat).

So

```
xargs -d'\n' mv -t /root/testing2/moved/ </root/testing2/goodfiles.txt
```